# Apache RewriteRule

Tags: mod-rewrite, tomcat

how do i combile these two rules btw,

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2 
RewriteRule (.*)/dsl/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2
```

i.e., a empty context path or a /dsl context path has to be replaced with /consumerDSLWGP. 
i tried

```
(.*)/(dsl)?/(.*)
```

but aparently even /dsl is getting appended in the URL.

```
115.241.55.20 - - [22/Dec/2011:10:20:47 --0500] [superclientstg2.sl.ca/sid#8fd3260][rid#9101a88/initial] (2) explicitly forcing redirect with https://superclientstg2.sl.ca/consumerDSLWGP/consumerDSLWGP/consumerDSLWGP/.../dsl
115.241.55.20 - - [22/Dec/2011:10:20:47 --0500] [superclientstg2.sl.ca/sid#8fd3260][rid#9101a88/initial] (1) escaping https://superclientstg2.sl.ca/consumerDSLWGP/.../dsl for redirect
115.241.55.20 - - [22/Dec/2011:10:20:47 --0500] [superclientstg2.sl.ca/sid#8fd3260][rid#9101a88/initial] (1) redirect to https://superclientstg2.sl.ca/consumerDSLWGP/.../dsl [REDIRECT/302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jsplang=(en|fr){1}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/DSLWGP/)
RewriteRule /(dsl/)?redirect\.jsp http://%{HTTP_HOST}/DSLWGP/dnsredirect.jsp?lang=%1
```

If it doesn't work:

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

May I ask you to add the rewrite log in your question?

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: thanks Olivier, i'll try this.... meanwhile, is redirectRule placed before any Alias definations?

Comment: rewriterules are usually after, but i'm not sure. this sounds logical to me that's all ;)

Comment: :) thanks it works ... how do i combile these two rules btw, RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2 RewriteRule (.*)/dsl/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2 i.e., a emty ocntext path or a /dsl context path has to be replaced with /consumerDSLWGP. i tried i tried (.*)/(dsl)?/(.*) , but aparently even /dsl is getting appended in the URL.

Comment: Please update your question, add what you're asking now, and don't forget to select your rules and click on "code" button to ident it properly ;) Answer me (= add a comment here to notify me) once it's done I'll do my best to help you (once again!)

Comment: done! did like you said... really need your help!!!

Comment: where is your log on your question?

Comment: have attached the log in the question....its looping basically...

Comment: Ok got it, updated my answer, tell me if it works. if it doesn't, try without the '/', like that: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(DSLWGP/)`. And if it works, check my answer =)

Comment: /(dsl/)? this works for me.. thanks a lot!!

Comment: it works... may I ask you to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite should do what you want:

```
RewriteRule (/dsl)?/redirect.jsp /DSLWGP/dnsredirect.jsp
```

You may find [this cheetsheat](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/) helpful.

Update as per the comments below:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/dsl/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2
```

Anything that is matched inside brackets in the pattern of the rewrite rule can be referenced as $[number] in the replacement where [number] is a number corresponding to the set of brackets you want.

Comment: so /dsl/redirect.jsp  will be redirected to /DSLWGP/dnsredirect.jsp and also anythig after redirect.jsp will also be appended after the  dnsredirect.jsp?

Comment: no rewritecond required?

Comment: Actually, my original answer isn't quite correct.  You don't need the [QSA] flag at all in this case.  QSA is only needed when you are adding extra parameters to the query string.  I have modified my answer.

Comment: hmm.. tried, dosen't seem to work.. i must be missing something. i'm not a apache person, i work on java, i have this application running in my servers which has many entry points.... so all i want to do is, eliminate creating different instance for different context path and redirect all to same instance of app. i.e, URL with https://.../dsl/... has to be redirected to https://../consumerDSLWGP/.. the only difference will be the context path.. the rest has to remain as it is while redirecting... is their a easier way to do it?

Comment: That doesn't match what you wrote in your question.  I'll add another rule to my answer for that requirement.

Comment: any tag i'm supposed to use this this? like [QAS] or sort of??

Comment: No, that should work as written.  Using [R] is often handy to help debugging.  It will send a 302 response sending the client to the new URL rather than rewriting the query.

Comment: :) thanks it works ... how do i combile these two rules btw,
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2
RewriteRule (.*)/dsl/(.*) $1/consumerDSLWGP/$2

i.e., a emty ocntext path or a /dsl context path has to be replaced with /consumerDSLWGP. i tried i tried (.*)/(dsl)?/(.*) , but aparently even /dsl is getting appended in the URL.